# Copying python lists

Tags: python, list, deep-copy

Just when I thought I had understood how Python lists work...

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b
[1,2,3]
>>> b[1]=100
>>> b
[1,100,3]
>>> a
[1,2,3]
```

So far,so good. I am initializing b with the contents of a, so that b points to a different object. As a consequence, changes in b don't affect a.

Now take a look at this other example:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b = a[:][:]
>>> b
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b[1][1] = 100
>>> b
[[1,2,3],[4,100,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> a
[[1,2,3],[4,100,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Why has the change in b affected a this time? What is different from the previous example?

Comment: Note that using `[:]` to copy is a bit cryptic - generally I find it much nicer to use `list()` or `copy.copy()`, depending on context. (Of course, as pointed out in answers, `copy.deepcopy()` may be what you want here).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The slicing operation `x[:]` makes a *shallow copy*. That means, the outer list is different, but is contains the exact same elements. assume `a = [[1]]`:

```
b = a[:] # is the same as:
b = [x for x in a]

>>> a[0] is b[0]
True
```

The double slicing (`[:][:]`) is doing nothing more than that - again:

```
b = a[:][:] # is the same as:
b = [y for y in [x for x in a]]

>>> a[0] is b[0]
True
```

A shallow copy of a shallow copy is, well, a shallow copy.

So `b` is still a shallow copy of `a` - these lists are different objects, but they contain identical elements. Then you mutate the inner list in `b`, but it is the same list in `a`.

2-level shallow copy can be done with `b=[x[:] for x in a]`. It extends the same way for n-level copy.

By the way, the term "shallow copy" has the same meaning for any class or container.

If you want real deep copy, you should consider using [deep copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Comment: A 'shallow copy'! I did not know that concept. Perhaps you can slightly edit the answer to explain it a little more (just a couple of words).

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez is it better now?

Comment: So, in the second example, b=a[:] and b=a[:][:] would have been exactly the same?

Comment: Almost: the latter will do the copying twice :). The results are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

The silcing [:] makes a shallow copy. but inner objects remain not copied so if they are mutable and You will modified them they will be modified ;) and in both list You will see this

use list comprehension

```
b = [i[:] for i in a]
```

or copy.deepcopy()

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [38]: import copy

In [39]: a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [40]: b=copy.deepcopy(a)

In [41]: b[1][1] = 100

In [42]: a
Out[42]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [43]: b
Out[43]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 100, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Read more @ http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html